# CPP dynamic memory recovery

Tags: c++11, memory-management, recovery

I'm wondering how the c++ compiler interacts with hardware in terms of dynamic memory allocation.

For example, when a c++ executable requests memory from the OS, how direct is that access?

If dynamic memory is assigned and then manually reassigned, is it still possible to recover lost data afterwards? Perhaps in OS records or as a result of memory assignment not translating exactly once interpreted by the compiler?

Is it possible to recover dynamically assigned data?

Comment: What do you mean by assigned and reassigned? Can ou put that in code? In general the chance to retrieve data that resides in seemingly deallocated memory is pretty high.

Comment: For the sake of argument, let's say it's assigned with new, at a set length, using a pointer, and then reassigned on the same pointer at the same size.

Comment: I don't have C++ on my current computer, or I would provide code.

Comment: My question is essentially: where is the dynamic memory /really/ coming from? If it is literally an adress in RAM, then if it is overwritten it cant be recovered. Unless there is some way to pull it out of the chip itself, directly.

Comment: Sounds to me a little like a XY-Problem. What are you trying to achieve? Wiping a password?

Comment: @MikeMB To be honest, I just don't like OS fascism, and the more I can learn about taking direct control over the hardware, the happier I will be.

Comment: The fact I don't actually know what goes on between me assigning memory, and the OS and compiler assigning it, does not sit well with me.

Comment: What do you mean by "OS fascism?" As someone who used to do a lot of coding back in the Bad Old Days of Windows 95 and Windows 98, trust me, you want the OS to do the nice things that it does!

Comment: Yes. Except when I want to do it myself, and if they won't let me, it's OS fascism.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer: For the details on how this is handled on Windows, have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa366525(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most operating systems and most compiler versions, when your program starts up some amount of memory is set aside for use for `new` and other dynamic allocations. The implementation of the memory manager partitions that memory up in some way and sets up some data structures to make it possible to easily service requests. When you request memory, if there's a block big enough to hold your request, the memory manager hands that block back, and when you deallocate something it puts it back into the pool for future consideration.

If you make a request and there's no space available, there are a couple of strategies the memory manager can use. On some systems, for very large allocations, the memory manager will just use `mmap` and have the OS give back a block of memory. On others, it will use a system call like `sbrk` to get more memory from the OS that then gets carved up the same way that the existing memory is.

If you leak memory in your program, then your program's memory manager will never recycle that memory and it will be unavailable to your program as long as your program is running. If your program never needs that memory again, that's totally fine - it can recycle previously-deallocated blocks - but if it needs more memory it will put in a request to the OS for more space.

All modern operating systems will automatically reclaim all the memory allocated by a process when that process quits, so as soon as any process terminates all the memory it allocated is freed. Barring a cruel and unusual operating system, a program that leaks a ton of memory will never permanently bar other programs from using that memory.

Something to keep in mind is that all the memory you're working with in your program is *virtual* memory and not *physical* memory. Each program thinks it has complete use of all the system memory, but in reality the OS is relocating memory all the time or paging things out to disk as needed. In that sense, even if your program did ask the OS for all the memory on the system, it wouldn't bar other programs from running as well - it would just cause the process to slow down like crazy as the memory it thinks it has keeps getting paged in and out.

Comment: Is there a way to force the OS to give a block of memory exactly as requested? If so, would it have to be executed I'm assembly?

Comment: Or, more appropriately, force the hardware to give access, as I imagine the OS is no longer involved at that point.

Comment: So like, if I wanted to allocate /exact/ addresses in the RAM chip that is in the machine.

Comment: Except in embedded environments, most OSes won't let you allocate blocks of memory at specific physical addresses. Even writing assembly code won't do that - the OS handles virtual-to-physical address mapping at the hardware level.

Comment: So when I bought my machine, I handed all that over to Microsoft? That's fantastic.

Comment: That's... not really what I said. The code you run is still running on your machine. The OS is just providing a number of useful abstractions to make it easier and safer to develop software. If you were to run Linux or Mac OS X, you'd have the same issues. The idea is to trade off direct control of the hardware in some specific ways (namely, control over physical memory) for safety (not being able to literally set your computer on fire by writing bytes to the memory addresses controlling different devices, preventing bad programs from trashing good programs, etc.)

Comment: As a matter of theory, then, to actually assign it directly you'd have to have a Bootable OS, or some such?

Comment: @bigcodeszzer You'd essentially need to (1) write code that runs inside the OS kernel, (2) replace the OS with one that does no safety checks at all and get a specialized compiler that outputs code that runs in that OS, or (3) switch to a more embedded context (say, Arduino) where the OS is much more permissive.

Comment: I was just looking some info on linux, and it seems like they give pretty-close-to direct access, exposed in functions like fmem. Probably going to try that out; bye bye windows.